# Elasticsearch 429 Too Many Requests _bulk with synchronous requests

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am using AWS Elasticsearch service. On dev environment there is t3.small instance.
I have approx 15 000 records that I want to index as a bulk. What I do is splitting this amount on chunks of 250 items each (or lower than 10 MiB). And run _bulk request with **refresh="wait_for"** option, one by one, and waiting until request is finished before sending the next one.
At some point, approximately on 25 iteration, the request is immediately fails with message

```
429 Too Many Requests /_bulk
```

Just in case, if chunk size will be 500 this will fail on 25/2 request (around 12)

It doesn't tell anything more. Just only this, I cannot understand why this happens if there is no anything else that could send bulk requests in parallel with me. I checked that the data size is lesser than 10MB.

What I already have

1. I send each request consistently, awaiting the previous one
2. Bulk request size is lesser than 10MiB
3. Each bulk request contains no more than 250 records in it (+ 250 to indicate that this is indexing)
4. I am using refresh="wait_for"
5. And even have 2 seconds delay before sending a new request (which I strongly want to remove)
6. Adding new instances or increasing storage space doesn't help at all

What could be the reason of having that error? How can I be guaranteed that my request will not be failed if I send everything consistently? Is there any additional option I can pass to be sure that bulk request is completely finished?

Comment: I'm stuck on exactly the same, did you ever figure out the cause? I am calling the bulk api in sequence, but when the number of docs is large it eventually gives 429 error... doesn't make sense it shouldnt matter how many docs if only doing one bulk request at a time

Comment: @Omiron so, in our case the problem was just with AWS. Their policy about cheep ES nodes is super ridiculous. That cheep instance is artificially choked by AWS load balancer. And that load balancer just has a limit of requests per some time

When we updated the instance to 1 tear higher - it started working like a super sonic. Eventually, all the problems were resolved

Answer (score 4):

A 429 error message as a write rejection indicates a bulk queue error. The es_rejected_execution_exception[bulk] indicates that your queue is full and that any new requests are rejected. When the number of requests to the Elasticsearch cluster exceeds the bulk queue size (threadpool.bulk.queue_size), this bulk queue error occurs. A bulk queue on each node can hold between 50 and 200 requests, depending on which Elasticsearch version you are using.

You can consult this link https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/resolve-429-error-es/ and check the write rejection best practices

Comment: As I said I send all the request one by one, there is no concurrency. When I check for thread_pools maximum value of write pools I see is 12 (of 10 000 possible)

Comment: Yo can enable more log info as described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-createdomain-configure-slow-logs.html and maybe you can find the exact error, once I had a similar error with bulk and was because the indexing was taking long time.

Comment: thank you, I will check this doc. But doesn't it mean, if you pass refresh="wait_for" that response will be returned only after indexing is finished? So this should mean for me that all resources are fine by the end of indexing

Comment: it suppose to work like you say, also check the Java heap max size, in one of the links I there with you refers the error to this cfg.

Comment: I'm stuck on exactly the same, did you figure it out? I am calling the bulk api in sequence but with large number of docs eventually 429 error... doesn't make sense

Comment: If you are doing a wait_for, the Queue is cleared off. 429s shouldn't occur. Maybe it is the AWS' artificial throttling at LB level as you mentioned in your comment directly to the question above